# 1987 mazda b2000 turn signal flasher location

Tags: mazda, flasher

I am wondering where the turn signal flasher for a 1987 mazda b2000 is located? My turn signals don't work, but my hazard works. Is there a separate relay flashers or, is it a fusable link?

Comment: I have the same issue with my 84 B2000
All my lights work but when I put the indicators on they just turn on instead of flashing, the hazards flash thoguh.

Answer (score 1):

Could be as simple as a fuse.  (NOT a fusible link.)

The hazard system is on a separate fuse that allows operation even with the ignition off.

Do the reverse lights work?  That's an important clue.

If the hazard lights flash, it's not the flasher module.

Here's a wiring diagram that should be very similar to your truck:

[image: Mazda 1987 B-series trucks Hazard and Turn]